# How to show error status after click the next button in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

It show error status when I am typing email address,

I need to show error status after click the next button, and also I added "more view friends" link, I set when I click  "more view friends" link, it will show one more textboxes at each link.

Now the error status show only first 5 textboxes.. and it didn't work other textboxes which is got by clicked link.

But in my jsfiddle link, "invite more friends" link didnt work, but in webpage it works fine.

javascript:

```
     $(document).ready(function() {
                        var container = $(document.createElement('div')).css({
            padding: '5px', margin: '0'});

            for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                $(container)
                    .append('<div><input type="text" class="input" id="tb'+i+'" placeholder="Email" /></div>');
                    }    
            $('#main').before(container);   

            $("input", container).keyup(function() {
                    validateEmail($(this));
                });
        var iCnt = 4;        
                function validateEmail(el) {
            if (!isValidEmail($(el).val())) {
        $(el).parent().addClass('invalid');
        return false;
            } else {
        $(el).parent().removeClass('invalid');
        return true;
            }
        }          

    });    

    var divValue, values = '';
    function GetTextValue() {

        $(divValue).empty(); 
        $(divValue).remove(); values = '';
        $('.input').each(function() {
            divValue = $(document.createElement('div')).css({
                padding:'5px', width:'200px'
            });

            values += this.value.trim();
        }
    });

         document.all.contact_list.value = values;            
    }
```

May i know, what is my mistake, how to fix this? thanks in advance.

Comment: where is this "invite more friends" link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to validate on next button click.hust replace:

```
$("input", container).keyup(function() {
     validateEmail($(this));
});
```

by:

```
$("#form").submit(function() {
    var inputs=$('.input');
    for(i=0;i<inputs.length;i++)validateEmail(inputs[i]);
    if($('.invalid').length!==0)return false;
});
```

to make 'invite more friends' link work add event handler.

```
$('#btAdd').click(function(){
    $(container).append('<div><input type="text" class="input" id="tb'+($('.input').length+i)+'" placeholder="Email" /> <label>This email is invalid</label></div>');
});
```

Comment: in your fiddle tou are not closing parent function tag in `$('document').ready`.just add `});` at the end of your js file. and invite more friends is in edited answer

Comment: edited again to check emails on submit form and if email is invalid stops submitting form. and remove `onclick="ValidateEmail()" ` from button

Comment: A small mistake, you missed to enclose input box with "div". Refer http://jsfiddle.net/u75vzjtm/9/  Check line number 43.

Answer (score 3):

Vinod's answer is correct, but you can do it a different way:

```
$("#main").on('keyup', 'input', function() {
    validateEmail($(this));
});
```

What's happening is you're creating elements that haven't been on the page yet, and therefore the event isn't being attached.

See more on the [jQuery on event](https://api.jquery.com/on/)

Also this is incorrect:

```
$(container).append('<input type=text class="input" id=tb' + iCnt + '  placeholder="Email" />');
```

You need to have double quotes

```
var id = 'tb' + iCnt;
$(container).append('<input type="text" class="input" id="' + id + '" placeholder="Email" />');
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, your problem is that the validation works only for the first 5 input boxes and does not work for the dynamically added input boxes.

If so,
You seem to bind event handler only initially.

```
$("input", container).keyup(function() {
    validateEmail($(this));
});
```

What you have to do is,

```
...
$('#btAdd').click(function() {
if (iCnt <= 19) {
    iCnt = iCnt + 1;
    // ADD TEXTBOX.
    var newTextbox = $('<input type=text class="input" id=tb' + iCnt + '  placeholder="Email" />');
    $(container).append(newTextbox);
    newTextbox.keyup(function() { //<<<< Bind keyUp for newly created textboxes also.
        validateEmail($(this));
    });
...
```

I hope this helps you.

**Edit**

On the other hand to make things easier you could simply use `$(selector).on();` method. [answered by @Lajos Arpad]

for more details refer [link](https://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: Actually its seems like asp page.. and i don't know very well javascript, can you please help? thanks

Comment: Yea sure... Please provide me the ASP source. Do you add input boxes dynamically through server script? If so, is it ASP.NET or ASP?

Comment: But we don't need asp right?.. for achieve my need, i think its enough our javascript and html..

Comment: Of course... this code should fix your problem. Go ahead and implement it. I have added a line on "$('#btAdd').click(function()" function (commented line). Let me know if it works.

Comment: your keyup() function is same as my code right? thanks

Comment: I believe this is not an ideal solution. You are trying to manually handle the register of keyup events, while you have the possibility to do this automatically, using .on(). See my answer.

Comment: @Lajos Arpad, your solution simplifies the process, but however then jquery starts listening to your parent DOM element, if any additional elements are added. So, when we know where we are adding the element, we could add event listener by ourselves. Isn't it? or am I missing something?

Comment: No, your answer is accurate, but overly complicates the problem. Whenever you write code to handle something which can be automatically done by a trusted (well-tested and performant) tool, you are introducing the potential of having bugs. This approach is not right for philosophical reasons, therefore I cannot up-vote it. It is accurate, therefore I cannot down-vote it. If you can mention in your answer that this can be done by .on() and describe what happens (in your opinion) under the hood, then you improve the level of your answer significantly.

Comment: OK. Sure, I will add this to my answer. Thanks

Comment: @VinodKumar: after took testing, i got one simple issue, if i click more link and type valid email in default textbox and invalid email in another textbox, it shows error all the text boxes. i need to show error status only for invalid email or blank field, may i know how to fix this, here is the updated link http://jsfiddle.net/u75vzjtm/8/ thanks

Comment: A small mistake, you missed to enclose input box with "div". Refer http://jsfiddle.net/u75vzjtm/9/  Check line number 43.

Answer (score 2):

The mistake is that you register `keyup` like this:

```
    $("input", container).keyup(function() {
            validateEmail($(this));
        });
```

This style, in itself is OK, but the problem is that this affects only elements, which are already existent. You need to use `.on`, like this:

```
$(outerSelector).on('keyup', innerSelector, function(ev){
    // stuff happens
});
```

The point is that `outerSelector` should point to element(s), which is/are already existent and the elements inside them, in conform to `innerSelector` are not needed to exist in the moment when you register the event.

EDIT: Addressing the particular problem

Since your fiddle has bugs, I cannot really test it, but intuitively, it seems that you should make this change:

```
container.on('keyup', "input", function(ev){
    validateEmail($(this));
});
```

Comment: after took testing, i got one simple issue, if i click more link and type valid email in default textbox and invalid email in another textbox, it shows error all the text boxes. i need to show error status only for invalid email or blank field, may i know how to fix this, here is the updated link http://jsfiddle.net/u75vzjtm/8/ thanks

Comment: @saina, that is completely unrelated to the question. Here is the fiddle where the problem was solved, but may I ask you to ask a separate question for that issue and write a comment here when you are done? Also, I still believe that the .on() answer is superior in comparison to the accepted one.

Comment: @saina, also, Vinod's answer is accurate, mentioned the .on() and showed how can you implement it as well.

Answer (score 1):

you are validation input box on every key up event this is the mistake you have done.

You should validate on input on click event on next button

Use following code at line no 11

```
$("#nextbutton").click(function() {    
   var inputs=$('.input');
for(i=0;i<inputs.length;i++)
   validateEmail(inputs[i]);
});
```

it will work properly

[Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/u75vzjtm/5/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code it may help you:

```
        function myfun() {
            var a = document.login.user.value;
            if (a == "" || a == null) {
                alert("u got it");
                return false;
            }
        }
```

[This is a DEMO fiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/bb60w9f4/1/)